# Как удалить запись из БД - через смежную таблицу с отношением - belongsTo - в Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, таблицы

У меня две таблицы - articles и downloads
Отношение между ними такое в модели Article -

```
public function downloads(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Corp\Download', 'download_id', 'id');
}
```

Я из контроллера ArticleController удаляю $article -

```
public function deleteArticle($article){
    $article->downloads()->dissociate();

    if ($article->delete()) {
        return ['session' => 'Материал удален'];
    }
}
```

А как сделать так, чтобы и запись, которая привязана к этой Article в таблице downloads также удалилась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно еще через БД:

Когда делали связь в миграции articles, например:

```
$table->foeign('download_id')->references('id')->on('downloads')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Именно `onDelete('cascade')` скажет БД удалять запись, если удаляется article

Comment: Вот за это спасибо! Но я уже допустим сделал данную миграцию - мне теперь нужно сделать rollback  - или же как-то можно через PHPMyAdmin добавить эти данные?

Comment: @ОлексійСлєпцов можно исправить в миграции и сделать php artisan migrate:refresh. Но тогда у вас полностью обновится БД (пропадут все записи) или можно добавить --step={количество шагов} и тогда обновятся только те таблицы - которые затронуты. Можете дать мне ваши любые контакты и помогу вам )

Comment: Можете добавить меня в скайп - butcher.vitamin,  если Вам будет удобно

Comment: @ОлексійСлєпцов добавил

Answer (score 0):

Реализуйте `observer` для модели `Article`,в котором при удалении будете удалять и соответствующие записи из `Download`

Comment: А как это сделать? Не сталкивался с Обсервером ещё ...

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers здесь можете прочтать об обсерверах.